# ClassNotFoundException starting Tomcat 8.0.27 from Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I got:

```
17-Nov-2015 17:53:22.314 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Excepción arrancando filtro HTTPMonitorFilter
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1780)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In theory `org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar` contains the class ...`MonitorFilter` , so I put

> org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar

on the path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/` ...and check the running process with:

> lsof -p 28083 | grep jar | grep
>   org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar

and :

> java    28083 darkglam  mem    REG        8,8   209867   525442
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar

But the exception is still here...what I'm doing wrong?.

Comment: In your configuration, did you mean to specify org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter?  It looks like you may have left the class name 'MonitorFilter' off...

Comment: 1) add you jar file in /WEB-INF/lib folder (2) Check your path setting as well